# Как получить IP-адрес в андроид приложении?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть сервер с ip-адресом и непосредственно андроид приложение. Если придется менять сервер, то пользователи останутся без данных, так как в приложении ip не поменяется, поэтому надо сделать получение ip-адрес независимо от самого сервера.

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: не используйте ip-адрес. используйте доменное имя.

Answer (score 1):

Самое лучшее - это DNS запись. Вы можете менять сколько угодно IP-адресов, но имя всегда можно перенести на новый адрес. В течении максимум 4 часов (по стандарту), хотя обычно в течение нескольких минут ваши пользователи снова смогут подключиться.